# perl regex replace single array element

Tags: regex, perl

I want to read a number of lines from a for loop and split them.
After that i want to do a replace on A SINGLE array element.

```
my @fs = split(';', $line);
$fs[0] =~ s/\"//g;
```

This doesnt work however. The line

```
$fs[0] =~ s/\"//g;
```

returns a compiler error.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you include the error, please?

Comment: That line has no errors, could yo have the whole code and the concrete error?

Comment: Never say "an error", like all errors are the same thing. That's about as useful as saying "a number", when referring to a specific telephone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line with `split` to

```
my @fs = split(/;/, $line);
```

because `split` takes a regex as its first operand.

I suspect the parse error you are seeing is due to an error somewhere else because the syntax of the code in your question is correct.

In general, always fix the *first* error diagnosed by the parser. Good parsers try to recover so as to report as many errors as possible, but this process is not always reliable. What is the exact text of the error you are seeing?

Comment: it's wrong. you *can* put **string** instead regex into `split`. but it always be **regex**

Comment: [`perldoc perlstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html): “Just because you *CAN* do something a particular way doesn't mean that you *SHOULD* do it that way.”

Comment: `use strict and use warnings` and also some idioms.

Comment: When i commented out the line of code, the script compiled as it should. It turned out that there was a windows-line-break in the line that was invisible until i opened it with VI. That is why that line was acting out.